# Подключение js плагина laravel mix

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь подключить [Air DatePicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html):

1. Запустил `npm i --save air-datepicker`.
2. После этого в 'resources/assets/app.js' добавил `require('air-datepicker');`.
3. Запустил `npm run watch`, он сообщил об успешной сборке.
4. Добавил `<input type='text' class="datepicker-here" data-position="right top" />` во `view`.
5. В главном шаблоне подключаю все собранные в один файл скрипты:

   `<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Ииии... Собственно, ничего не происходит.
Не выскакивает `datepicker`, скрипт попросту не обрабатывается.
Также не работают и другие скрипты, которые я хотел бы подключить.

В чём загвоздка? Как собрать нужные мне скрипты в этот файл и чтобы это всё работало при переносе на сервер без `node.js`?

C `webpack` не работал и буду очень благодарен, если объясните как это дело должно работать. Я привык подключать нужные мне скрипты в конец страницы и всё отлично работало, но хочу уйти от этого, т. к. со временем там уже не разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `app.js` сделай

```
global.datepicker = require('air-datepicker');
```

Comment: так нужно будет со всеми плагинами, которые я хочу использовать в любом месте?

Comment: @ThreegunD Один из вариантов. Можно еще как - то настроить алиасы в вебпаке

Comment: @ThreegunD в ларавеле так jQuery и подключается. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: спасибо, вы немного открыли глаза. А вообще моя проблема заключалась в том, что я не подключал стили плагина)

Answer (score 0):

1. Первое, что хочется тебе сказать читай здесь [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix)
2. Далее все будет зависеть от способов, как ты будешь этим всем пользоваться, ты можешь все склеить в один файл при помощи

   mix.styles([
       'public/css/vendor/normalize.css',
       'public/css/vendor/videojs.css'
   ], 'public/css/all.css')
   .js([
       '/resources/assets/js/app.js',
       '/node_module/.../vendor.js'
   ],'public/js/build.js').version();

Потом, где-то воткнуть `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">` и `<script src="{{mix('/js/build.js')}}"></script>`

3. Вариант сдлеать всю сборку в созданном файле (по умолчанию ) bootstrap.js  в нем добавить require('библиотеку') и все дальше юзать как в созданном по умолчанию шаблоне

Так же нужно не забыть, что если у тебя не лайф события их лучше подключать в mounted в `Vue.nextTick(function{\*Тут инициализация*\})`